# conditionally stop iteration of for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, iterator

In a typical C-like language a for loop gives you more control over iteration. I'm wondering how to do the equivilent

```
for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
  do_things(A[i]);
  if (is_true(i)) {
    i--;
  }
}
```

in Python?

In other languages I opt to use their container based for loop constructs, but they typically have vanilla for loops that I can use for situations like this. How do I get more "control" when iterating in Python?

I imagine the answer to this is very basic, but the search terms are muddied with other questions.

Comment: You have to use the equivalent while-loop, or write an iterator with this capability.

Comment: I recommend that you play with the Python iteration capabilities.  As many people have learned, you *can* alter the iteration variable within the loop.  However, evaluation of array size and other side effects may surprise you, as Python has some different optimizations and variable handling.

Comment: Also, please note that making such changes in the iteration parameter is a dangerous practice.  In the development groups I've joined over the past 10-15 years, the code you posted would fail review.

Comment: Your example doesn't stop the iteration, that's done with a `break` statement, which exists in Python.

Comment: `is_true(i)` is `False` when the iteration starts at `i=0` , resulting in `i` becoming -1 when it is then incremented back to zero, thus creating an endless loop (assuming you are just evaluating the boolean value in pseudo-code, although it could be a function that evaluates to something else).  The general construct for this structure is `enumerate`, although any change to `i` would only persist for that cycle before continuing its enumeration. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: It's just a sloppy explanation of a loop that doesnt continue to the next element until some condition is met. I didn't explain clear enough I guess

Comment: @2c2c Use `continue` instead then. Decrementing `i` is the wrong action.

Comment: *What* condition?  If it didn't evaluate to True with previous values of `i`, why would it now evaluate to True?  Rather than focus on the mechanics, you may want to focus on your objectives. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

The best equivalent in Python would be a `while`-loop:

```
i = 0
while i < A.length: # If `A` is a regular Python container type, use `len()`
    do_things(A[i])
    if  is_true(i):
        i -= 1
    i += 1
```

Note however, as said in the comments, iterating like this over a container is more often than not, a bad idea. You should review your code and make sure you actually need this behavior.

---

**EDIT**

> It's just a sloppy explanation of a loop that doesnt continue to the next element until some condition is met. I didn't explain clear enough I guess

Use `continue` instead then. Decrementing `i` is the wrong action:

```
i = 0
while i < A.length:
    do_things(A[i])
    if not is_true(i):
        continue
    i += 1
```

Better yet, you can ditch the `while`-loop all together and use `enumerate`:

```
for i, el in enumerate(A):
    if not is_true(el):
        continue
    # do work
```

Comment: `A.length` won't usually work (too much Javascript?).  You probably meant `len(A)` :-)

Comment: @mgilson Well. not exactly. I wasn't exact;y sure what `A` was. Whether it was a custom type, or a simple array. I opted to keep accuracy to the original code while translating, but your probably right. So I'll ad a note.